# Crystal Report 7 Alternate Row Color

Tags: crystal-reports-7

I'm trying to make a report by using Crystal Report 7. But I'm having trouble when I tried to make the odd detail become white and the even detail become gray

Here what I've tried
[image]

I'm waiting for the answer. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though it's an old post, maybe some people still need it. I happen to still use cr 7, I use this logic and this works fine.

if right(totext(recordnumber / 2),2) = '00' then White else Black
if right(totext(recordnumber / 2),2) = '00' then true else false

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link, this might help you.
http://victoriayudin.com/2009/03/31/alternating-shading-for-lines-in-crystal-reports/

OR
Try this:
if RecordNumber mod 2 = 0 then crWhite else crSilver.